# I have created a Chore Tracker in Python but keep running into issues to get it working properly

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Chore Tracker in Python where you can input your chore and hours and it gets stored in a dictionary. Then when ready, you can print_summary() and it tells you each chore, the time spent on it and the total hours spent on chores.
I am not able to get it to work properly and I am not sure what the issue is.

This is the code I have so far.

```
class ChoreTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tracker = {}

    def add_hours(self,chore_name, number_of_hours):
        menu_char =''
        while menu_char != 'n':
            self.chore_name = input('What is the name of the chore?')
            self.number_of_hours = float(input('How many hours was the chore?'))
            self.tracker.append({chore_name},{number_of_hours})

            menu_char = input('Do you want to add another chore? (y/n)')
    #Add inputs and ask if there is more to add, append to self tracker
   
    def print_summary():
        total_chore_hours = 0
        for each in tracker:
            total_chore_hours = number_of_hours + total_chore_hours
            print(f'{chore_name}: {number_of_hours:.2f} hours')
        print(f'Total: {total_chore_hours:.2f} hours')

ChoreTracker.add_hours('sweeping', 0.75)
ChoreTracker.add_hours('laundry', 1.5)
ChoreTracker.add_hours('working', 11.5)
ChoreTracker.add_hours('mopping', 0.5)
choretracker.print_summary()
```

I have tried that code above, but I keep getting the error ChoreTracker.add_hours() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number_of_hours' and I have no idea how to update the code to fix the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have now updated the code to

```
class ChoreTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chores = {}

    def add_hours(self,chore_name, number_of_hours):
        menu_char =''
        while menu_char != 'n':
            self.chores["Chore_Name"]:(chore_name)
            self.chores["Number_of_Hours"]:(number_of_hours)

            menu_char = input('Do you want to add another chore? (y/n)')
        return chore_name, number_of_hours
    #Add inputs and ask if there is more to add, append to self tracker
   
    def print_summary(self):
        total_chore_hours = 0
        for each in self.chores['Key']:
            total_chore_hours = self.chores.get('number_of_hours') + total_chore_hours
            print(f'{chore_name}: {number_of_hours:.2f} hours')
        print(f'Total: {total_chore_hours:.2f} hours')

tracker = ChoreTracker()

tracker.add_hours('sweeping', 0.75)
tracker.add_hours('laundry', 0.5)
tracker.add_hours('working', 6)
tracker.add_hours('mopping', 0.5)
tracker.add_hours('laundry', 1)
tracker.add_hours('working', 5.5)

tracker.print_summary()
```

But I keep getting KeyError, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class:

```
chore_tracker = ChoreTracker()

chore_tracker.add_hours('sweeping', 0.75)
```

Python implicitly passes the `self` argument as the current instance. You're getting the error because you're not calling the method on an instance.

Comment: Hi ndc85430,
I have implemented your suggestion into the code and it works so far, but now I am running into this error. I updated:
while menu_char != 'n':
            self.chore_name = input('What is the name of the chore?')
            self.number_of_hours = float(input('How many hours was the chore?'))
            self.tracker["Chore"]:(chore_name)
            self.tracker["Hours"]:(number_of_hours)
And
chore_tracker = ChoreTracker() and also ChoreTracker.print_summary()

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using `self` in your function signature, you've made `ChoreTracker` a **non-static** class, so it expects to be instantiated.

You're trying to use `ChoreTracker` the class itself, rather than an instance, in the code section `ChoreTracker.add_hours('sweeping', 0.75)...`.
The function signature of `def add_hours(self, chore_name, number_of_hours):` expects 3 arguments, and `self` isn't passed in because you've made it non-static.

To fix this issue, make a new instance, for example: `myTracker = new ChoreTracker()`, then call the functions via `myTracker.add_hours('arg1', 0)`.

I would highly recommend reading more into classes and trying a more basic example, as there are a few issues with your `add_hours` functions. Check out the [Python Docs!](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for that response, I have implemented it into the code. I will check out those Python Docs!